# Select tag populated by jquery and $_POST at the same time

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a select tag which its options are prepopulated by jquery with ajax calls to a database onload of the page. However there can be another option in which on the HTML side within the select option there is sth like this.

```
<select id="brandList" name="brand">
     <?php                      
      if(isset($reference_shirt['brand']))
    {
    echo '
     <option>' . $reference_shirt['brand'] . '</option>
      ';
    }
    ?>
 </select>
```

But the php part is not working. How do I determine which will be loaded first ? or is there a variable i can set to do that? THanks in advance

Comment: This last one will be processed _before_ the page - and the js script with the ajax code - will be printed out. So yes, this comes before, then the page is sent to the browser, then the browser (on page load, in your case) fires a request to php, which as you can see happens "a lot" later

Comment: how do i determine if isset(var) the load the variable else load jquery?

Comment: Please post your JavaScript. I have the feeling that you're overwriting your `select` `option`s with JS, instead of appending them to the `option`s generated by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For loading values using PHP in CI you have to pass values from the controller
as:

```
$this->load->view->('view_name',$arrValues);
```

and array should be like:

```
  $arrValues['reference_shirt']=array('brand'=>$val);
```

Then only you can access those values in view.

After getting values in view , Create one hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="brand" value="<?php echo isset($reference_shirt['brand']))? $reference_shirt['brand']:''?>">
```

Now using Jquery you can check whether brand has value or not as:

```
 if($("#brand").val()==''){
    //Load values using ajax
 }
```

In this way!

Hope it will help you!